# Impossible to make wireshark rpm?

Tags: qt, makefile, centos, wireshark, rpm

I am using centos 6.5, and trying to build a wireshark 2.2.2 rpm from the source code.

this is what I get after running ./configure

```
The Wireshark package has been configured with the following options:
                   GLib version : v2.28.8
                Build wireshark : no
            Build wireshark-gtk : yes (with GTK+ v2.24.23)
                   Build tshark : yes
                  Build tfshark : no
                 Build capinfos : yes
                  Build captype : yes
                  Build editcap : yes
                  Build dumpcap : yes
                 Build mergecap : yes
               Build reordercap : yes
                Build text2pcap : yes
                  Build randpkt : yes
                   Build dftest : yes
                 Build rawshark : yes
              Build androiddump : yes
                  Build sshdump : no
                Build ciscodump : no
              Build randpktdump : yes
                    Build echld : no

   Save files as pcap-ng by default : yes
Install dumpcap with capabilities : no
         Install dumpcap setuid : no
              Use dumpcap group : (none)
                    Use plugins : yes
   Use external capture sources : yes
                Use Lua library : no
            Build Qt RTP player : no
          Build GTK+ RTP player : no
         Build profile binaries : no
               Use pcap library : yes
               Use zlib library : yes
           Use kerberos library : yes (MIT)
             Use c-ares library : no (name resolution will be disabled)
            Use SMI MIB library : no
         Use GNU gcrypt library : yes
         Use SSL crypto library : no
             Use GnuTLS library : no
 Use POSIX capabilities library : no
              Use GeoIP library : no
             Use libssh library : no
        Have ssh_userauth_agent : no
                 Use nl library : no
          Use SBC codec library : no
```

I have updated ran this command too to resolve any dependency issues which might be there..

```
yum install -y gcc-c++ bison flex gtk2 gtk2-devel libpcap-devel
```

But this is the error I keep getting when i run **make rpm-package**

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/wireshark-2.2.2/ui/gtk'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/wireshark-2.2.2/ui/gtk'
 (cd ui/qt && make  top_distdir=../../wireshark-2.2.2     distdir=../../wireshark-2.2.2/ui/qt \
     am__remove_distdir=: am__skip_length_check=: am__skip_mode_fix=: distdir)
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/wireshark-2.2.2/ui/qt'
  LRELEASE   wireshark_de.qm
/bin/sh: -silent: command not found
make[2]: *** [wireshark_de.qm] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/wireshark-2.2.2/ui/qt'
make[1]: *** [distdir] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/wireshark-2.2.2'
make: *** [dist] Error 2
```

dont know what to do about it, has anyone else had successfully made **wireshark 2.2.2 rpm** for centos 6.x

Comment: you might try rebuilding a src.rpm. Search one on http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3 ; download it and run:  `rpmbuild --rebuild ****.src.rpm`

Comment: note; there is no *el6.src.rpm available; so you'll have to use one from opensuse or something similar

Comment: @ChrisMaes : that is not working due to various dependent libraries which are not available for centos 6.5 eg, qt5, gtk3, etc.
since source rpms are build using those only.
so, what i was trying is, compile the code again without using these new libraries  and then make a rpm using command "make rpm-package" which internally uses rpmbuild only.